# PHP Profile Image Viewing Code Not Working

Tags: php, html, image, user-profile

I am having a site that need to show users their own profile picture. But I am unable to do so. I have built the code but it is not working. Can anyone suggest me what could be the reason. The code for showing image is as follow:

```
 <p>
    <?php
    //We check if the users ID is defined
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        $dn = mysql_query('select avatar from users where id="'.$id.'"');

        echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($dnn['avatar']).'" alt="Profile Picture" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" />';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'This user don't have an avatar.';
    }
    ?></p>
```

Comment: Where you are fetching the records? you are only executing the query. Use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` to fetch the records.

Comment: show us the HTML output (view source)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to get the result:

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('databasename', $con) or die(mysql_error());

$dn = mysql_query('select avatar from users where id="'.$id.'"') or die(mysql_error());
$dnn = mysql_fetch_assoc($dn);
echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($dnn['avatar']).'" alt="Profile Picture" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" />';
```

Also you can try moving your code from `mysql_*` because those functions are deprecated, you can try MySQLi or PDO. [Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a nice tutorial to get you started on PDO.

Comment: Do you have MySQL connection setup ? Does the row name is `avatar` ?

Comment: no i dont have the mysql connection and avatar is the name of column where link to images are kept.

Comment: Can u also tell me how to create mysql connection

Comment: don't forget to setup username, password and database name

Comment: please tell I am dying for this solution. Do I only Have to put this is PHP code

Comment: NO. you have to modify it with your username and password. Please read http://www.php.net

Comment: ok I have modified it but the image is still not being shown I am just getting the ALT tag

Comment: it says --- <p>
 <img src="" alt="Profile Picture" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;" /></p>

Comment: tell what could be the possible reasons

Comment: Select query wrong, you didn't added `?id=1` or what id you pass, I've updated the code, you can add `or die(mysql_error());` to query to see if there is an error

Comment: not working still same page source. should i give you my whole page source

Comment: I don't need your page source, I don't know how your database is, if you made the connection correctly, if there is `avatar` for that `id`.

Comment: i dont have specified $id so how can .$id. can know what he has to do?